# Is it possible to rerender a pageBlock using Javascript?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

Is it possible to rerender a pageBlock using Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

1. Create an action function like `<actionfunction name="hitme" rerender="the_block"/>`
2. In the Javascript function simply execute `hitme();`